# Shift_JIS to UTF_8 conversion of full width tilde [～] character returns a thicker character

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm processing Shift_JIS files and outputting UTF-8 files. Most of the characters are displayed as expected when viewed in a text editor, except for the full width tilde character [～]. It becomes thicker similar to this: [**～**]. 
*note: this is not the same character, I just don't know how to type it here so I bolded it*

When I type it manually in the UTF-8 file, I get the regular version.

Here is my code:

```
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (
        new FileInputStream(inFile), Charset.forName("Shift_JIS")))) {

    try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter (
            new FileOutputStream(outFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    }
}
```

I also tried using "MS932" and also tried not using IOUtils.

Comment: Try using `x-SJIS_0213` instead.

Comment: that didn't work, but "x-MS932_0213" did. would this charset have any side effects?

Answer (score 0):

To read Shift_JIS files made with Windows, you have to use `Charset.forName("Windows-31j")` rather than `Charset.forName("Shift_JIS")`.

Java distinguish `Shift_JIS` and `Windows-31j`. "Shift_JIS" in documents for Windows means Windows-31J(MS932) in Java. On the other hand, "Shift_JIS" in documents for AIX means Shift_JIS in Java.

Character mappings for Windows-31J and Shift_JIS are slightly different. For example, `～` (`0x8160` in Shift_JIS) is mapped to `U+301C` in `Shift_JIS`, and `U+FF5E` in `Windows-31j`. Microsoft IME uses `U+FF5E` (FULLWIDTH TILDE to represent the character `～`.